# How does knockout hide object properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js but getting my speed with it. One thing I am really frustrated about is if I do `JSON.stringify(koModel);` I get empty object `{}`.

I know I need to use `ko.toJSON(koModel);` and I get what I need but now I am interested in:

**how does knockout hide all the properties so `JSON.stringify()` doesn't enumerate them ?**

**UPDATE**

As per @dandavis comment I have tested and yes - `JSON.stringify()` doesn't show functions at all so as my models were filled with `ko.observable()` and `ko.observableArray()` I was getting an empty object.

Comment: you can do that with .prototype, Object.defineProperty(), or by using functions as sub-objects.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for `defineProperty`! and I didn't really know that functions are not shown in `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Knockout doesn't try to "hide" anything, it's just a side-effect of an  `observable` functions use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually used knockout, but a fairly good guess is that the model properties are actually accessor functions that delegate to the wrapped object (and do more stuff like notify on changes). Here is some code that exhibits the same behavior:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b : 2 };

var ko = Object.create(null, {
  _obj : { value : obj, enumerable: false },

  a : { 
    get : function() { return this._obj.a },
    set : function(v) { this._obj.a = v; console.log('Dispatch change event!') }
  },

  b : { 
    get : function() { return this._obj.b },
    set : function(v) { this._obj.b = v; console.log('Dispatch change event!') }
  }
});

ko.b = 3;
console.log(ko.a, ko.b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(ko));
```

And yes, `JSON.stringify` doesn't take into account functions (as per [JSON spec](http://json.org/)) and non-enumerable properties. Both can be observed in the example above.

As per haim770's comment, it's even more straight forward, as the properties themselves are functions, which are simply ignored by the JSON.stringify method:

```
var ko = {
  a : function(v) { 
    if (!arguments.length) return obj.a;
    else { obj.a = v; console.log('Dispatch change event!') }
  },
  b : function(v) { 
    if (!arguments.length) return obj.b;
    else { obj.b = v; console.log('Dispatch change event!') }
  },
}
```

Comment: +1 But Knockout doesn't use getters and setters the way you presented. the actual use is `someProp()` for getter and `someProp(newValue)` for setter.